# Given $x_1=1,x_2=2,x_{n+2}=3x_{n+1}-x_n\forall n\in\mathbb N$. Find $x_n$.

Tags: sequences-and-series

> Given $x_1=1,x_2=2,x_{n+2}=3x_{n+1}-x_n\forall n\in\mathbb N$. Find $x_n$.

I tried to find ways to telescope, but failed. Please help. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a general way to solve those type of recurrences, through the characteristic polynomial of the relation.
$$
x_{n+2}+ax_{n+1}+bx_{n} = 0 \leadsto X^2+aX+b=0
$$
Here, it'd be $X^2-3X+1$. The roots are $\phi=\frac{3+\sqrt{5}}{2}$ and $\bar{\phi}=\frac{3-\sqrt{5}}{2}$.Any solution $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}^\ast}$ is of the form $x_n = \alpha \phi^{n-1} + \beta \phi^{n-1}$ (since the two roots ${\phi},\bar{\phi}$ are distinct). Then use the initial conditions $x_1$ and $x_2$ to get $\alpha,\beta$.

Comment: Coincidentally, $\phi = \left(\frac{1+\sqrt{5}}{2}\right)^2$ so since $x_1=F_1$ and $x_2=F_3$, where $F_k$ is the Fibonacci numbers, you can figure out that $x_n=F_{2n-1}$, I think.

Comment: Rk: If the two roots were equal (or, in general, if for a recurrence relation of order $k$, some roots have multiplicity $m> 1$), the solution would have a slightly different form; for a recurrence relation of the second order, if the characteristic polynomial has only one (double) root $\phi$, the general form of a solution is $$x_n=(\alpha+\beta n)\phi^{n-1}$$

Comment: I was going to suggest (on the assumption that the Fibonacci sequence would have been seen before this problem was assigned) just working out the first few terms of the given sequence, (1,2,5,13,34) and recognizing them as every second Fibonacci number.  Once you've noticed that, it's easy to prove, by induction, that the pattern continues.

Answer (score 0):

The set of sequences of complex numbers (actually any field, but let's keep things simple) $(x_n)$ satisfying
$$
\begin{cases}
x_0=a\\
x_1=b\\
x_{n+2}=rx_{n+1}+sx_{n}
\end{cases}
$$
can be made into a vector space by defining addition componentwise and multiplication by scalars as multiplying each term by the scalar. Since a sequence is determined as soon as the $0$ and $1$ term are fixed, this vector space has dimension $2$.

Let's try finding two linearly independent sequences in it, by first looking at the simplest kind, that is, geometric progressions. So, when does the sequence $(t^n)$ belong to the vector space? It should satisfy
$$
t^{n+2}=rt^{n+1}+st^n
$$
for all $n$, in particular for $n=0$, that is,
$$
t^2-rt-s=0.
$$
Conversely, if $t$ satisfies this equation, the corresponding geometric progression belongs to the vector space.

If the polynomial $X^2-rX-s$ has distinct roots $\alpha$ and $\beta$, we want to show that the sequences $(\alpha^n)$ and $(\beta^n)$ are linearly independent. If
$$
p(\alpha^n)+q(\beta^n)=(0)
$$
where $(0)$ denotes the constant zero sequence, we have, in particular
$$
\begin{cases}
p+q=0\\
p\alpha+q\beta=0
\end{cases}
$$
and the determinant of the system is
$$
\det\begin{bmatrix}1 & 1\\\alpha&\beta\end{bmatrix}=\beta-\alpha\ne0,
$$
so the system has a unique solution, with $p=q=0$.

Therefore, for any sequence $(x_n)$ in the vector space there are coefficients $p$ and $q$ such that
$$
x_n=p\alpha^n+q\beta^n \qquad \text{for all $n\ge0$}
$$
and $p$ and $q$ can be uniquely determined by plugging in the given values for $x_0$ and $x_1$.

If the polynomial has only one (double) root $\alpha$, then we can see that the sequences $(\alpha^n)$ and $(n\alpha^n)$ are linearly independent: the linear system to look at is
$$
\begin{cases}
p=0\\
p\alpha+q\alpha=0
\end{cases}
$$
that surely is satisfied for $p=q=0$. Notice that $\alpha\ne0$, unless the recurrence is the trivial one $x_{n+2}=0$.

Of course this can be generalized to any linear recurrence equation.